# Clojure - Exception handling

Tags: exception, clojure

I want my web page to behave as expected when there's an exception by a function, now (openid/validate r) doesn't return a value unless a user is redirected from /login. But since this is a home page, I want it also be  visible without a problem. So I wonder why the "if" there doesn't work as I expect?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at /
NullPointerException [no message]

tfs.routes.home/[fn]
home.clj, line 48

--> line 48
(if (openid/validate r)
```

So instead of NullPointerException, I expected (home-page r) to execute.

(openid/validate r) fails in itself and causes an exception because its not fed by the needed parameters, is that the cause? If so how can I fix it? If not, why my (home-page r) function doesn't get executed?

```
(if (openid/validate r)
     (show-response (:params r))
     (home-page r))
```

Comment: it would really add to the question, if you could support claims like "doesn't work" with errors, exception, code...

Comment: @cfrick added the error.

Comment: You want to learn about `try/catch`. However, you also want to find out what is actually causing the NPE.

Comment: @schaueho I tried it with try/catch, still getting NPE, it is because openid/validate is not being given required parameters, but then else part of the "if" should execute, but it doesn't...

Comment: Show more code, please.

Comment: @schaueho After you I tried again, I didn't use `catch` statement before I don't know what I was thinking, thanks for reminding it.

Answer (score 0):

So I did this with `try/catch`, it seems to be working fine now. Just not sure if I still should use the `if` there or not since I'm using `try/catch`?

```
(GET "/" [:as r] (home-page r)
(try (if (openid/validate r)
     (show-response (:params r))
     (home-page r))
(catch Exception e (home-page r))))
```

Comment: Throw out the `if`, it's unnecessary. Still -- figure out if `openid/validate` throws the NPE or the call to `show-response`. If it's the former, you should change (or wrap) the code, so that it returns a boolean value (`false`) instead -- quite obviously, a failed validation doesn't constitute an _exceptional case_, but an expected one (cf. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GoodExceptionManagementRulesOfThumb.aspx)